# cant get current User from API with axios

Tags: express, axios, passport.js

i have a problem to get my auth User. When I call my route where the current user is in i become no Data in my Vue file.

Backend:

```
 var app = express();
app.use(cors({
  methods:['GET','POST'],
  credentials: true,
}))


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cookieParser('test'))

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(session({
  secret: 'test',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const port = 3000


app.use(express.static('public'))

//Passport setup

const apiRoutes = require('./apiRoutes')
app.use('/api', apiRoutes)
```

Passport config:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'password'
    },
    function(username, password, done) {
        userModel.findOne({
          username: username
        }, (req, res) => {
        
        const match = bcrypt.compare(password, res.password).then(result => {
            if (result) {
                return done(null, res, {message: 'hat geklappt'})
            } else {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'hat nicht geklappt'})
            }
        })
    })
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });
```

Route:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let user = req.user;
    res.json(
      user
    );
});
```

My API is not empty but i cant get the data from Axios get

API:
[APi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTSbi.png)

and my Empty data field:
[vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVoMc.png)

i dont know what i can do because i have not so much experience and iam really thankfull for help

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

set `content-type: application/json` in the header like this:

it's a sample

```
var axios = require('axios');
var data = JSON.stringify({"username":"username","password":"password"});
let domain = "localhost";
let port = "3000"
let url = `http://${local}:${port}/api`
var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: '',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

the request is not added to the question, but you can change your request base on my answer